# From http to https - htaccess and URL rewrite - Too many redirect error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https, url-rewriting

I have a site with the following **working code** in .htaccess to get friendly URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /?s=scheda&id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

Since I installed a SSL certificate, I need to update my .htaccess to redirect **http contents to https**. I found this code:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

And I tried to add it to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /?s=scheda&id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

but I get a "Too many redirect problem" error.

What's wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates you are looping, and I can see only one rule that could loop :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

This redirects a.html to ?s=a.html which matches this same rule.

But it shouldn't work in http too. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Please consider that the following code is correctly running on http.
    
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /?s=scheda&id=$1&slug=$2 [L]  
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]`

The loop problem happens when I add the second part:

`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: You should put the http -> https redirect first.  Why do you only use L flag and not R,L ? L is known for its problems ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r ). Try adding END flag as suggested by the doc. If still not working, make your logs verbose and come back with the logs ( LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3 in httpd.conf )